# How can I connect Alexa(echo plus) to a VPN?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to connect my Alexa device to a vpn so that I can access services which are available on vdi. Can anyone please help with the same.

Comment: Are you asking this question as a developer of an Alexa Skill, or as an end-user of an Alexa-enabled device?